# AWS Newly created RDS snapshot is not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have a RDS database running in an AWS account. I'd like to copy it to another account to use as a base for a new deployment of the application. I use the CLI like so:

```
aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot \ 
  --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier snapid \
  --db-cluster-identifier rdsid
```

This command succeeds (and if I log in into the AWS console, I can see the new snapshot). But when I try to modify its attributes using

```
aws rds modify-db-snapshot-attribute \
  --db-snapshot-identifier snapid \
  --attribute-name restore \ 
  --values-to-add '["other_account_id"]'
```

Then I get the following error:
 `An error occurred (DBSnapshotNotFound) when calling the ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute operation: DBSnapshot not found: snapid`

If I can share the snapshot, I could then create a new instance in the other account using this snapshot.

Is there a better way to share a RDS instance cross-accounts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mixed up [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/) calls a bit. You should use one of the matching command pairs as shown below.

**Aurora DB Cluster API**

> **create-db-cluster-snapshot** - Creates a snapshot of an Aurora DB cluster.
>
> **modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute** - Adds an attribute and values to, or removes an attribute and values from, a manual DB cluster snapshot.

**RDS DB API**

> **create-db-snapshot** - Creates a database snapshot.
>
> **modify-db-snapshot-attribute** - Adds an attribute and values to, or removes an attribute and values from, a manual DB snapshot.